# dot sourcing not working when starting script from desktop

Tags: powershell

i have a powershell script which dot sources stuff from 2 other scripts. 
When i run the script from ISE it works fine, 
but when i run it from desktop by right click and select "Run with PowerShell" it errors 
with module not exists etc..

my script sources the two files like this

```
. c:\SIJ\scripts\userstory_gui_part.ps1
. c:\SIJ\scripts\userstory_function_part.ps1

#region gui events {

$Create.Add_Click( {

$Tbname = $TableNameId.Text

$TbViewName = $TableViewNameID.Text

$CustName = $CustomerNameID.Text

$global:UsrName = $AdUserNameID.Text

$global:usrPasswd = $AdpasswordID.Text

$global:Ticket = $CherwellTicketID.Text

 kunde $($CustName)

$returnValueDataTask = Create-UserStory $UsrName $usrPasswd $Tbname $TbViewName $CustName $Ticket | Out-String

$returnValueErwinTask = Create-ERWIN-UserStory $UsrName $usrPasswd $Tbname $TbViewName $Ticket | Out-String


$b = $returnValueDataTask | Select-String -Pattern '([DWH-]{4}\d{4})'

$global:userstoryid = $b.Matches.Groups[1]

$c = $returnValueErwinTask | Select-String -Pattern '([DWH-]{4}\d{4})'

$global:erwinuserstoryid = $c.Matches.Groups[1]

[System.Windows.MessageBox]::Show("følgende blev oprettet $($returnValueErwinTask) og 
$($returnValueDataTask)", "Oprettelse af Userstories i JIRA")

$CreateFileUploadButton.Enabled = $true

})

 $CreateExitButton.Add_Click( {

 $form.Close()



})



$CreateFileUploadButton.Add_Click( {

Write-Host "Du trykkede upload knappen"



$filename =SelectFileToUpload







Add-Attachment $userstoryid $filename $UsrName $usrPasswd

Add-Attachment $erwinuserstoryid $filename $UsrName $usrPasswd

Write-Host "ok"



})

#endregion events }





#endregion GUI }

[void]$Form.ShowDialog()
```

How can i ensure that my scripts startup with the environment needed from desktop

there error is

```
Unable to find type [System.Windows.MessageBox].
At S:\UO4\DWH\SIJ\scripts\create_data_userstory-feature edition.ps1:29 
char:1
+ [System.Windows.MessageBox]::Show("følgende blev oprettet $($returnVa ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: 
(System.Windows.MessageBox:TypeName) [], RuntimeException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : TypeNotFound
```

Comment: Are those dot sourced scripts in the same directory as the parent script or in a different directory?

Comment: Please provide the error message as well. Try to hunt down this error  by commenting out anything but the dot sourced lines and the very last line. what does this show?

Comment: it seems adding this reference Add-Type -AssemblyName PresentationFramework worked. I will test it now